# Why performance decreases when I call a C functions in Python?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I am using a random number generator as is suggested by [Daniel Lemire](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/03/19/the-fastest-conventional-random-number-generator-that-can-pass-big-crush/). It works very efficiently in C when it is compiled with `gcc -O3`. It only takes **3.9 seconds** to generate **10^9** random numbers. However, when I call the C function in Python, it is about **100 times slower**.

Here is the C code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
 
static __uint128_t g_lehmer64_state = (__uint128_t)513543212345676543;

uint64_t lehmer64() {
  g_lehmer64_state *= 0xda942042e4dd58b5ull;
  return g_lehmer64_state >> 64;
}
```

However, I would like to use this C function in Python. Therefore, I create a library using GCC:

`gcc -o liblehmer64.so -shared -fPIC -O3 rand_test.c`

Then, I use the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module and test the performance in Python:

```
from ctypes import c_uint64, CDLL

lib = CDLL('liblehmer64.so')

lehmer64 = lib.lehmer64
lehmer64.restype = c_uint64

for i in range (1000000000):
  rnd = lehmer64()
```

## Question

- Why the Python code is 100 times slower than C code?
- How can I improve the performance of the Python code?

Comment: Crossing language boundaries is quite expensive, so calls from python to c have to do a lot of things: Pass arguments to C code -> do something in C -> pass the return value back

Comment: did you try to implement the algorithm directly in Python ?

Comment: @JeffUK you're right. Comment deleted

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I also implemented the function in python. It is slightly faster but there is still two order of magnitide difference.

Comment: It's not crossing language boundaries that is expensive.  I daresay it is not inherently slower for Python to call a C extension function than to call a Python function.  Nor does the C extension function have to do anything that an equivalent Python function does not also have to do, albeit perhaps behind the scenes.  I would be inclined to suppose that the main thing that makes this slow is generating so many Python objects.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the feedback. I do not understand your last sentence. Can you please elaborate on which python objects do you mean?

Comment: @Ali, more or less everything in Python is an object.  In particular, each random number you generate is represented as an object in Python if it is represented on that side at all, and you're generating a billion of them.  Each one requires a comparatively large amount of memory relative to the corresponding C number, has extra state that needs to be initialized and managed, and places a load on Python's garbage collector that I would expect to scale superlinearly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: python's garbage collector is based on reference counting and those numbers are reaped almost immediately. So there is certainly a lot of object creation and deletion but I'd expect the result to be constant space and linear time. Still, the cost of creating integers is probably a significant part of the observed overhead.

Comment: @rici, superlinear scaling assumes that uncollected objects would build up.  If that doesn't happen then ok, GC still adds its own linearly-scaling cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the Python code is 100 times slower than C code?

Because there's a lot to do when calling the function. The function call itself is expensive.

> How can I improve the performance of the Python code?

If you want a huge list of random numbers, then you can write a C function that returns a huge list, thus minimizing the number of calls.

You could for example implemement a queue in python that stores 10000 random numbers. You initialize it with the C function mentioned above. Then the queue automatically calls the function every time you pop the last number from the queue. If that's also too slow, then maybe you should code functions using the random numbers in C too. Creating a huge list is quite expensive in Python.

An example of something that would benefit quite much from writing as a C function is an `is_prime(x)` function, that is, a function that returns true if `x` is a prime and false otherwise. Especially if we're talking about very large numbers. This case has these two key properties:

- There is very little data sent to and from the `is_prime(x)` function. You send it a simple integer and return a boolean.
- For large `x` this is a very heavy operation

My example with creating a queue fails on the first point. There would be quite a lot of data sent between C and Python.

Your function fails on the second point. The calculation is very lightweight compared to the function call overhead.

Comment: Agreed, and +1.  It should be noted, however, that generating a huge list of Python objects of any type is going to be expensive no matter what.  If the OP needs many random numbers then they should look into ways to avoid that, such moving more of their program into pure C, using Cython to achieve similar, or perhaps using representations that don't require a separate Python object for each number, such as Numpy arrays.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I addressed it now

Comment: Simple looping in Python is slow.  Compare "for i in range(1000000000): pass" to an equivalent C loop (1.86 s on my system).  `timeit` hasn't returned yet in minutes of running the Python version.

Comment: Excellent answer, I also wanted to point out that OP likely doesn't have to write the C code themselves with libraries like [numpy.random](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#module-numpy.random)